# coloring padding area set with @media

Tags: html, css

for a WP I am using

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section {
    padding: 50px 0;
  }
}
```

for auto padding between several sections. Now, for one section I want to add a background image and a gray transparent box in front of it:

```
section {
  padding: 100px 0; #which does not do anything, can change it to random values. 
}
section .background1 {
  background-color: #222222;
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
section .bg-layer {
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50, 0.6);
    top: 0 ;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

My html code looks the following, with some text and so on inside:

```
<section>
  <div class="background1">
    <div class="bg-layer">
      <div class="container">
```

This works fine in principle, but the padded areas are not filled in with the backgroud image and I can't make that work. So I basically want the image andd gray areas extending towards the general padding area for this one section. Can anyone help or describe the best work-around? Thx a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want to achieve.

```
section {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
section h2.section-heading {
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
section h3.section-subheading {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Droid Serif", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}
section .background1 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
section .bg-layer {
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50, 0.6);
    padding: 50px 0;
}
section h2.bg-section-heading { 
  color: white;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
section h3.bg-section-subheading {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Droid Serif", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  section {
    padding: 50px 0;
  }
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.bg-darkest-gray {
  background-color: #222222;
  padding: 0;
  }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92f0xxnz/2/)

Comment: I am not quite sure but this should be it: https://jsfiddle.net/92f0xxnz/ The almost black background is the part that should be covered by the image and the grayish part above the image. Thx!

Comment: Updated the fiddle

Comment: I cannot see any changes on the link. What do I have to do to see your changes?

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Form your own answer.

Comment: He solved it perfectly and changed the answer, you can undo the negative rating. And to you vijayscode: Thx a lot, this is really, really helpful! Can you explain really quick what's the trick behind the two little changes?

Comment: The problem was that you were adding the `padding` to the `parent div section`, therefore the child div  `bg-layer` was not taking full height and full width of parent that was the reason the background was not of full width and height. What I did was removed padding from the parent div and added it to `bg-layer` so still bg-layer has some padding but now it will take full height and width.